# Regexp & VBA - loop through cells, return matched value in adjacent cell

Tags: regex, vba, excel, for-loop

If in column A,I had values like
**A**

A0394

948B0129

Zkjs333

0a0401a

09ab28

and I wanted to return matches where there are 2 alpha followed by 2 numeric characters using regular expressions and VBA (without using a custom function)
**B**

js33

ab28

What would the code look like?

Comment: Why not try and write it first ?  Have you tried anything?

Comment: I threw it away because I was not running properly and I've never used regexp with vba before. Here's something along the lines of what I had
`sub test()
Dim strPattern As String
dim regex As Object, str as string
set regex=createObject("VBScript.RegExp")

with regex
.pattern="[a-z]{2}[0-9]{2}"
.global=true
end with
for each thing in range("A1:A4")
set matches= regex.execute(thing)
thing.offset(0,1)=regex.execute(thing)
next`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You almost had it. Since you are searching for only one occurrence of the pattern, say the first, you can have it as `matches(0)`, but first check if there are matches using `matches.count`.

```
Sub Test()
  Dim cel As Range, matches As Object
  With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    .Global = True
    .Pattern = "[a-zA-Z]{2}[0-9]{2}"
    For Each cel In Range("A1:A10")
      Set matches = .Execute(cel.Value2)
      If matches.Count > 0 Then cel.Offset(0, 1).Value = matches(0)
    Next
  End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You Regex is correct and should something like this to define it properly in VBA

```
Private Sub simpleRegex()
    Dim strPattern As String: strPattern = "[a-z]{2}[0-9]{2}"       
    Dim regEx As New RegExp      


        With regEx
            .Global = True
            .MultiLine = True
            .IgnoreCase = False
            .Pattern = strPattern
        End With
```

with

```
regEx.Test(strInput)
```

you can check if a String match or not.

you can find a very deep answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22542834/how-to-use-regular-expressions-regex-in-microsoft-excel-both-in-cell-and-loopshttp://).

Comment: using the code in example 3 (looping through range) of the very deep answer: what would you write in the if statement (if regex.test(strinput) then) to return the value of the matches found? I tried msgbox (regex.execute(strinput)) but it returns an error: "Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment"

Comment: regex.execute(strinput)  return all the possible matches i think that doing `msgbox (regex.execute(strinput))  you are settings too much arguments. @machump

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub test()

    Dim matches, regex As Object, c As Range
    Dim i As Long

    Set regex = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    With regex
        .Pattern = "[a-z]{2}[0-9]{2}"
        .Global = True
    End With

    For Each c In Range("A1:A4")
        Set matches = regex.Execute(c.Value)

        'if only one match expected...
        If matches.Count > 0 Then
            c.Offset(0, 1) = matches(0)
        End If

        'if can be multiple matches...
        'For i = 1 To matches.Count
        '    c.Offset(0, i) = matches(i - 1)
        'Next i
    Next

End Sub
```